# GraphUser object returns null "getUserName" while fetching friends from facebook in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

In my android application i want to fetch my facebook friends and for that i am using `facebook-android-sdk-3.7`. I referred `FriendPickerSample` which is provided by `facebook-android-sdk` itself. Here, it returns friendlist as a list of `GraphUser`. Now, i want to fetch `username` of all friends but the problem is that it doesn't provide `username` of friendlist. It provides all other personal information of friends except `userName`.So what should i do to get `username` of friends? Please suggest any solution for that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the code inside that sample which is fetching the user details, so I can not suggest you some changes to fetch the username.

Anyways, that sample must be providing you the `user_id`. So, you can make this call to get the username of that friend-

```
/{user-id}?fields=username
```

[Demo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=595273610%3Ffields%3Dusername)

Comment: Yes..its fetching userID nut it will be very long process to fetch userName of all friends through userID.

Comment: Then could you find how is it fetching all the friend? I mean where is it making the API call

Comment: i am using sample code provide with facebook-sdk.You can find that with sdk itself. The sample name is `FriendPickerSample`.

Comment: Sorry but you have to do this research. As I'm not in to the android dev